# Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Code**

```
    deviceIds = mbln.getGCMId();  //getting arraylist
    String[] s = new String[deviceIds.size()];
    for (int i =0; i < deviceIds.size(); i++)
        s[i] = deviceIds.get(i);     //converting to array
    logger.debug(s);
    JSONObject info = new JSONObject();

    info.put("registration_ids", s); //device registration token
    info.put("title", "HI1");
    info.put("body", "hello");  

    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(info.toString());
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);   //response = 400
        }
```

**Error**

*java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send*

It worked with "to" but to send notifications to multiple devices I used "registration_ids" where I have to pass array of String of tokens. So something is going wrong there.

Comment: Means you formatted your input incorrectly. Also [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages) looks like the REST API you should be using.

Comment: May be the array is not in correct format. First I'm getting arraylist from another function, then 
**String[] s = new String[deviceIds.size()];
    for (int i =0; i < deviceIds.size(); i++)
        s[i] = deviceIds.get(i);**

converting arrayList to String array 's' and passing it directly in this form **info.put("registration_ids", s);**

Comment: I think its because I'm converting the json to String  here **wr.write(info.toString());** and when I convert the array inside the Json read like this **{"registration_ids":[Ljava.lang.String;@7dd74598,"title":"HI1","body":"hello"}**

Comment: Any other alternative way to escape from this conversion

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So The answer is:

I was using **String Array**, instead of that I simply used ArrayList to store Strings and it solved the problem.

So instead of

`String[] s = new String[deviceIds.size()];`

create an ArrayList,

`ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: This ain't the solution.